# Angular2 subscribing to changes to @Input in Child Component

Tags: angular

I have a parent and child component. Parent component has `index` and passes this through to the child component as an `@Input`. This `index` value constantly changes in the parent component, and inside my child component, I want to run a function everytime the Parent component changes `index`. This has a slide component that constantly changes it. How can I achieve this? I've tried with the below code (`this.index.subscribe(() =>`), but I'm getting that it's not a function everytime I try and initialise the subscription.

EDIT: There is no related code in the `Child` template that could impact this, so it's not provided. `ngOnChange` doesn't seem to work as the change is happening in the directive as opposed to the `parent`'s template.

Child:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: "child",
    templateUrl: "components/child/child.html",
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() index: string;
    currentIndex: any;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}

    ngOnChanges(){}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log("index " + this.index);
        this.currentIndex = this.index.subscribe(() => {
             console.log("index " + this.index);
        })
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.currentIndex.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

Parent:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Page} from "ui/page";
import {ChildComponent} from '/components/child/child.component'

@Component({
    selector: "parent",
    template: "<child [index]="index"></child>",
    directives: [ChildComponent]
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    index: string = "0,1";

    constructor(private page: Page) {
    }



}
```

Comment: First off, `ParentComponent`'s template should be `template`, not `templateUrl`. Besides, could you show the template for `ChildComponent` ?

Comment: `index` in `ParentComponent` **is a `string`** and `ChildComponent` expects it to be an `Observable<any>`. Is that how you are using them?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you get `Error: this.index.subscribe is not a function`.

Comment: please provide the code of your `template`

Comment: Where's `this.slides` coming from? From your code, it can't be anything other than `undefined` (it is not being set anywhere), which throws an error at `let SlidesXml = this.slides.nativeElement;`.

Comment: @acdcjunior: I have updated and forked bnussey's plunker to show that this works when you are changing the variable inside the code. Here is the  [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n2vSZc64ZF2jtJz5dRwS). You don't need to use an observable.

Comment: @DanSimon yeah, I'd agree you don't need to use `Observable` as type. But the the way it is just smells terrible. If you want an `Observable`, then write the type as such, not as a `string`, even if you can get around it, even if it works.

Comment: @acdcjunior: sorry, I got my names mixed up! Got my wires all crossed on who was asking the question and who was responding.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Input-var.html

To quote:

> Angular automatically updates data-bound properties during change
>   detection.

If you need to do some processing on the input, look at the get and set.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter

From the documentation, here is an example.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'name-child',
  template: `
    <h3>"{{name}}"</h3>
  `
})
export class NameChildComponent {
  _name: string = '<no name set>';
  @Input()
  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
  }
  get name() { return this._name; }
}
```

You don't need to use an observable.

Comment: sometimes you want to re-trigger a method of your component after any input changed... then using `ngOnChanges()` is a lot simpler than running that method in each setter of every input, I guess.

Comment: for those who feel the setter technique is tedious, checkout [subjectize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subjectize), which wraps the setter under the hood and you don't need a private variable.

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use `ngOnChanges` life hook. From Angular`s [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges):

> ngOnChanges: Respond after Angular sets a data-bound input property.
>   The method receives a changes object of current and previous values.

Check the example below to see how you can use it:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges  } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    Value:
    <span>{{ value }}</span>
    <br />
    <br />
    Number of changes: {{ numberOfChanges }}
  `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() value: any;

  private numberOfChanges: number = 0;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.numberOfChanges++;
  }
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XjD1jjCnqiFdbhpTibIe

Comment: What directive do you mean that is updating the `index`?

Comment: Please, check the context inside the `SlidesXml.on("start", (event) => { ... }` event

Comment: @bnussey: I have modified Alexandre Junges's plunker and forked it, this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/n2vSZc64ZF2jtJz5dRwS?p=info) shows that even changing the code in the directive will update the child.

Answer (score 14):

`ngOnChange` is called each time an input parameter changes. You even have it in your `Child` component, but it's not implemented correctly:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
  // check the object "changes" for new data
}
```

More details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges

**Update**: `index` in the parent component is a `string`. For some reason it became an `Observable` in the child component.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you advise how to implement it correctly with some more detail please?

Comment: Seems this only work on initial load - for array inputs, at least.

Comment: @RemiSture, technically, arrays are passes by reference. If you are reassigning array, then it'll be triggered, but if you modify array, reference stayed unchanged. You may need to notify child component. Check https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html#observables.

Comment: updated link for documentation
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks#!#onchanges

Answer (score 4):

Another solution for "transforming" the changing value into an observable should be

```ts
@Input() status: Status;
private status$: Subject<Status>;

constructor() {
    this.status$ = new Subject<Status>();
}

ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {

    this.status.next(this.status);
}
```